# Why I cant be able to change the UITableViewCell detailTextLabel's frame (just the label's position)?

Tags: iphone

I am having a table view with default UITableViewCell of style UITableViewCellStyleValue2. I just want to move detailTextLabel few pixels to the right. I know it makes no sense to adjust its width and height :). I am trying to set detailTextLabel's frame with my x and y value. But its not affecting the its frame. I prefer to use default UITableViewCell, in this case, over a customized cell because the default UITableViewCell automatically manages the text alignment and centering of the labels..

1. How to change UITableViewCell detailTextLabel's frame?
2. Am I allowed to change its frame?

Thanks everyone..

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You said you want to change the frame of detailTextLabel without using the custom cell implementation then the answer to your questions will be :-

1. It is not possible
2. No, it is not possible

For that you have to use custom cell , and add probably a textview or a label to the cell's contentView according to your needs

Answer (score 2):

They have the default size with the table view cell.You can do the custom implementaion.Here is the example I am giving to you

```
UILabel *productNameLabel = [[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(105, 35, 60,20 )];
    productNameLabel.textColor = [UIColor whiteColor];
    productNameLabel.backgroundColor=[UIColor clearColor];
    productNameLabel.text=@"Name";
    [cell.contentView addSubview:productNameLabel];
    [productNameLabel release];
```

Hope this will help you.Try to use the custom implementaion.